# Why did the transaction fail?

Tags: transactions

I got the transaction ID, why can't I find this transaction?id:onivQ7UehosXojRz6afTR7FZ9L3GfyLrkQa3G6J5rLys6qYoPW9
It should be that the transaction was not broadcast, but how can I find out why?
Interface ‘/injection‘ return is successful

my operation is {u'branch': u'BMHqTybVHTwZcjFBL9zM3NRtBeN3VD6BNPukCmZf8JfTLKSFJG4', u'contents': [{u'source': u'tz1cxTyu7dwLUvXKt4mE85Rwr1XLB9byY2Vc', u'kind': u'transaction', u'fee': u'1607', u'storage_limit': u'60000', u'destination': u'tz1RVjS45cLxJHbQNQfvEf9u8ASkv5CC4hmp', u'amount': u'320000', u'gas_limit': u'800000', u'counter': '1505527'}]}

Comment: How did you try to inject it? Did you get any error message?

Comment: I tried it again, no error message.
And the log looks normal.
Jun 24 16:57:02 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.Pt24m4xiPbLD_1: injecting operation op5u2L4oB1BnpNWxRVrbjbfEwrX8v4UDYu6R87jCVtfUcQSbdgG
Jun 24 16:57:02 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.Pt24m4xiPbLD_1: Pushed: 2019-06-24T08:57:02-00:00, Treated: 2019-06-24T08:57:02-00:00, Completed: 2019-06-24T08:57:02-00:00

Answer (score 3):

Technically there's nothing wrong with your transaction and it didn't fail. But no baker wanted to (by default) include it in a block because of the low fee in relation to the gas & storage limits. So after 50 minutes it was cleared from mempool. There's no reason to set gas & storage limit to the maximum values possible in this case. You can find some recommended values to use here:

```
| Operation     | Gas       | Fees          | Burn              |
|-------------- |-------    |-----------    |----------------   |
| transfer 1ꜩ   | 10200     | 0.001281ꜩ     | 0 or 0.257 (*)    |
| transfer 1Mꜩ  | 10200     | 0.001284ꜩ     | 0 or 0.257 (*)    |
| origination   | 10000     | 0.001265ꜩ     | 0.257             |
| delegation    | 10000     | 0.001257ꜩ     | 0                 |
| revealing     | 10000     | 0.001268ꜩ     | 0                 |
```

http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/protocols/004_Pt24m4xi.html